How can I export all submission attachments with the OpenReview API?
I have access to the program chairs console of a venue in OpenReview. I followed https://docs.openreview.net/how-to-guides/data-retrieval-and-modification/how-to-export-all-submission-attachments:
Using:
#pip install openreview-py
import openreview

# API V2
client = openreview.api.OpenReviewClient(
    baseurl='https://api2.openreview.net',
    username='[redacted]',
    password='[redacted]'
)

notes = client.get_all_notes(invitation = "Your/Venue/ID/-/Submission")
for note in notes:
    if(note.content.get("pdf")):
        f = client.get_attachment(note.id,'pdf')
        with open(f'paper{note.number}.pdf','wb') as op: 
            op.write(f)

worked well to download all submission attachments.
I now want to to download all the supplementary materials for all submissions.
for note in notes:
    if(note.content.get("supplementary_material")):
        f = client.get_attachment(note.id,'supplementary_material')
        with open(f'paper{note.number}_supplementary_material.zip','wb') as op: 
            op.write(f)

supplementary_material matches my venue's config:
{
    "supplementary_material": {
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "file",
                "extensions": [
                    "zip",
                    "pdf"
                ],
                "maxSize": 100,
                "optional": true,
                "deletable": true
            }
        },
        "description": "All supplementary material must be self-contained and zipped into a single file. Note that supplementary material will be visible to reviewers throughout and after the review period, and ensure all material is anonymized. The maximum file size is 100MB.",
        "order": 7,
        "readers": [
            "confname/2024/Industry_Track",
            "confname/2024/Industry_Track/Submission${4/number}/Area_Chairs",
            "confname/2024/Industry_Track/Submission${4/number}/Reviewers",
            "confname/2024/Industry_Track/Submission${4/number}/Authors"
        ]
    }
}

I'm getting the error message:
C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\openreview\python.exe C:\Users\dernoncourt\openreview\get_all_pdfs.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\openreview\Lib\site-packages\openreview\api\client.py", line 141, in __handle_response
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\openreview\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api2.openreview.net/attachment?id=[redacted]&name=supplementary_material

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\openreview\get_all_pdfs.py", line 26, in <module>
    f = client.get_attachment(note.id, 'supplementary_material')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\openreview\Lib\site-packages\openreview\api\client.py", line 609, in get_attachment
    response = self.__handle_response(response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dernoncourt\anaconda3\envs\openreview\Lib\site-packages\openreview\api\client.py", line 156, in __handle_response
    raise OpenReviewException(error)
openreview.openreview.OpenReviewException: {'name': 'NotFoundError', 'message': 'The Supplementary Material file was not found (2024-07-19-3654726)', 'status': 404, 'details': {'path': 'note.content.supplementary_material', 'reqId': '2024-07-19-3654726'}}

Process finished with exit code 1

How to fix it?
